# Resizing the JavaApplication according to resolution

Tags: java, jframe, autoresize

I would like to know how to resize the `java application` ie Frame according to screen size or resolution of screen , in other words resolution independent ..
I am searching somethings simular to

```
Softgroup .NET Forms Resize v7.0
```

My main aim is if i run my application in android using emulators it should work properly but at same time my laptop resolution n screen size is much bigger then of my mobile ...

Comment: If you use a layout manager and allow your Swing components to retain their default preferred sizes, everything will be a size that is appropriate for the system you're on.  (I assume you're asking about Swing since you have tagged the question with [tag:jframe].)

Comment: i am using AbsoluteLayout

Comment: A consequence of using a null layout is that you have to manually accommodate system configuration, such as font size and screen resolution, which is going to require a lot of additional code.  The best way to solve your problem is to use an actual LayoutManager;  then you won't have to worry about it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
```

In `screenSize` you will get a `Dimension` which have:

```
screenSize.width
screenSize.height
```

Comment: if i use it then what about all controls inside the frame?

Comment: then you will get the height and width as you can see in my answer

Comment: by this i can resize the frame but what about the controls ie compnents like jtextfield etc inside the frame..

Comment: First, use this code and see what happens, if it doesn't succeed, you need to consider using `GridBagLayout`